# How to append a line from .txt file without new line character "/n"

Tags: python, txt

I have to read a `txt` file with for example this:

```
test
test2
test3
test4
```

If I use a this code

```
read_of_string = open("mylink.txt", "r")
read_of_string = read_of_string.readlines()
print(read_of_string)
```

a output is `["test/n","test2/n","test3/n","test4/n"]`

if I use this code

```
print(read_of_string[0])
```

output is "test" (enter)

I have to append it into a

```
listofstring = []
listofsting.append(read_of_string)
```

it is not working
Output should be a list with strings without enters like

```
["test","test2","test3","test4"]
```

Comment: those are `\n` not `/n` -- the escape character for a newline

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use the [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method:

```
read_of_string = read_of_string.read().splitlines()
```

So in your code, it should be:

```
read_of_string = open("mylink.txt", "r")
read_of_string = read_of_string.read().splitlines()
print(read_of_string)
```

But do note that it is a better practice to use the `with` handler to open files:

```
with open("mylink.txt", "r") as r:
    read_of_string = r.read().splitlines()
    print(read_of_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this work?

```
a = ["test\n","test2\n","test3\n","test4\n"]
b = [item.rstrip() for item in a]
print(b)
['test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```